# Android : Capturing internal audio with SDK

Tags: android, audio, sdk, android-ndk

I am trying to capture internal audio in an application where user can merge effects on a recorded voice. Till now I have found articles and solutions which are pointing to the use of NDK like the following link http://xzpeter.org/?p=254, but as I'm still relatively new to Android I am trying to avoid getting into NDK as of now. My question is that is it possible to acheive this goal with using SDK?

Comment: There's no API specifically for recording the audio output from your app (or any other app). Not in the SDK, and not in the NDK. What you can do is to, whenever you write an audio buffer to your `AudioTrack` or OpenSL ES `BufferQueue`, write the same data to a file. This assumes that your app also handles all necessary mixing and encoding/decoding.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the reply. But I was wondering how are the online radio or other radio applications able to record audio internally? Any light on that will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would be application-specific. One way could be to create a simple relay / proxy server within your application that fetches the audio data from the remote server and feeds it to your `MediaPlayer` or whatever playback API you're using. Since your server sees all the data as it downloads it, it can save it to a file or do whatever it likes with it.

Comment: I just thought of it as something that may assist me with my application, but thanks for putting light on it. I am going to try your approach of writing the same data to a file